# DB2 Warehouse load with csv file not including column names

Tags: csv, db2

When I do a DB2 Warehouse load using a csv file the load completes successfully but none of the column names match what was in the csv file. E.g. Column name in csv is "Patient" but in the DB2 warehouse table it ends up being "Column 0". Is there a load option or DB2 Warehouse config option to avoid this behaviour?

Doing a load of the same csv file for DB2 on Cloud works fine.

Comment: It depends on exactly whiich tool you use to perform the loading action. Be specific, show the exact command.

Comment: I'm using the db2 management console to do the load

Answer (score 0):

In the Load Data section of the admin console there is a toggle switch called 'Header in first row' that needs to be set on, otherwise you get the default column names, COLUMN_0 etc:

Off:

[image]

On:

[image]

Comment: The header in 1st row shows green so is on. Still no column names but if we toggle header in 1st row off then back on again it shazzamm the column names show up. ??? In anycase thx for your help.

Comment: i don't see a "detect data types" like you show. All my data types end up being listed as varchar

Comment: Ah OK it sounds like you've hit a bug there then.  My example was using the cloud console - haven't got an installation to check at the moment but if you're using DMC on prem it might look slightly different.